# "English accent speaker "

Tags: word-order

"Now let's listen to an English accent speaker."

I fell like it doesn't sound good. Much better seem alternative constructions with "of" or "with", right?

What do you think?
Thanks

Comment: [correction: I feel, doesn't sound right]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's plausible if you treat it as a compound adjective, and I wouldn't be shocked to hear someone condense the description in that way if they had to list numerous speakers with different accents (such that it does become a kind of categorizer).

But it would only mean what you could say more clearly using a construction like "a speaker with an English accent".